# React native: how to grab default value of Input to the state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, native-base

I'm using `NativeBase` and `ReactNavigation`.

On LoginScreen sometimes we have an empty input for email, and sometimes with filled `defaultValue` (when we redirected to LoginScreen from SignUpScreen).

```js
const defaultEmail = this.props.navigation.getParam('email', '');
```

```html
<Input
  placeholder="Email"
  defaultValue={defaultEmail}
  onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
/>
```

If we don't change the field, login failed, because state doesn't contains default value.

I tried to do `this.setState('email':'defaultEmail')` in render function (and I suppose it is deprecated, and I get infinity loop), I tried to move this logic to `componentDidMount`, `componentWillMount` but it doesn't work too, I suppose on this step of component's lifecycle we haven't navigation props.
I didn't check idea to do this with refs.

The question is: how to grab `defaultValue` to state?

Comment: should work on componentiDidMount(), you can try it on constructor too

Comment: @BrunoMazzardo no, it doesn't work. neither from constructor or componentDidMount

Answer (score 0):

Use the constructor lifecycle method to initialize state with the default parameter.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        defaultEmail: props.navigation.getParam('email', ''),
    }
{
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. if i did in constructor `console.log(props.navigation.getParam('email', ''))`, there will be '' empty string. But then, in render() function this.props will contains 'email'...